# Qt - Converting QString to Indices of QByteArray - Dividing device ID into 3 indices

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qstring, qbytearray

I am using QtSerialPort to send serial messages across a COM port to an INSTEON PowerLinc 2413U Modem. I can hardcode and send messages just fine, however I need to send the same message using variable device IDs. The following is the structure I used to send static messages:

```
QByteArray msg;
bool msgStatus;   

msg.resize(8);
msg[0] = 0x02;
msg[1] = 0x62;
msg[2] = 0x1B;
msg[3] = 0xE9;
msg[4] = 0x4B;
msg[5] = 0x11;
msg[6] = 0x05;
msg[7] = 0x00;
send(msg,&msgStatus);
```

Index positions 2,3,and 4 represent the device ID. "1BE94B" in this instance. My function accepts the device ID that the action should be executed for via QString.

How can I convert the QString to fit the needed structure of 3 indices. I successfully get each byte of the 3 byte address using the following:

```
devID.mid(0,2)
devID.mid(2,2)
devID.mid(4,2)
```

My Target implementation is for the QByteArray to look like this:

```
QByteArray msg;
bool msgStatus;   

msg.resize(8);
msg[0] = 0x02;
msg[1] = 0x62;
msg[2] = devID.mid(0,2)
msg[3] = devID.mid(2,2)
msg[4] = devID.mid(4,2)
msg[5] = 0x11;
msg[6] = 0x05;
msg[7] = 0x00;
send(msg,&msgStatus);
```

I have tried many different conversions schemes, but have been unable to resolve what I need. Ultimately my `msg` should be structured as:

```
    02621DE94B151300
```

The only way I have successfully seen the intended device action is by individually assigning each byte in the QByteArray, using `msg.append()` does not seem to work.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: maybe you can use `QByteArray::fromHex(const QByteArray& hexString)` to append the values

Comment: I believe if anything, it would be `msg=STRINGOFCOMMANDS.toHex()`, however I tried something very similar and it did not work. I am needing to convert my three byte device address into three separate indices with a datatype that aligns with the above `msg[x]=` structure.
Or, if there is a better implementation I would love to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that QString is unicode/short based and not char based. For me it works when I use `toLocal8Bit`

```
QByteArray id;
idd.resize(3);
id[0] = 0x1B;
id[1] = 0xE9;
id[2] = 0x4B;

QString devId( bytes );

QByteArray msg;
msg.resize(8);
msg[0] = 0x02;
msg[1] = 0x62;
msg.replace( 2, 3, devId.toLocal8Bit() );
msg[5] = 0x11;
msg[6] = 0x05;
msg[7] = 0x00;
```

If your id is text, and not bytes, then the fromHex must be added:

```
QString devId( "1BE94B" );
msg.replace( 2, 3, QByteArray::fromHex( devId.toLocal8Bit() ) );
```

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much for your reply. I am still not sure how that would work for what I need exactly. I have modified my post to reflect my intended target implementation. My problem is that my device ID originates from a string that is passed to the function, opposed to being hard coded into indices as you show above.

Comment: I modified my example to match your revised question.

Comment: I added an additional example for when the id is text from and not bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I will not be able to really check this until after work.

What we are doing here is using `QByteArray & replace ( int pos, int len, const QByteArray & after )` by saying: Starting at index 2, replace three positions (2,3,4) with the Hex formatted devID, correct? This works because each of the elements will be 1 Byte ~ 2 Hex Characters.

Comment: Yes, that's  it. `toHex` receives 6 characters because `toLocal8Bit` converts devId into bytes. `toHex` then converts the 6 characters into 3 bytes values. These three bytes values are then written into message at offset 2.